# SSIS - Get difference in minutes between two dates in Script Task

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I have written script component using vb.net and using following:

```
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::StepStartTime")
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::StepEndTime")
```

Assigned value to this at Start
vars("User::StepStartTime").Value = Date.Now

Assigned value to this at End 
vars("User::StepEndTime").Value = Date.Now

I'm struggling to find a function which can give difference in minutes between these two above dates.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract them...

```
DateTime tStart = Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::StepStartTime");
DateTime tEnd = Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::StepEndTime");

// Capture differnce between two datetime values
TimeSpan tSpan = tEnd.Subtract ( tStart );

// Capture tSpan in minutes
Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::DiffInMinutes") = tSpan.TotalMinutes;
```

References

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Comment: Its giving me error on this line - expression does not produce a value             Dim tStart As DateTime = Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::StepStartTime")
            Dim tEnd As DateTime = Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::StepEndTime")

Comment: And when I try this it still gives me error Dim tStart As New DateTime and then tStart = vars("User::StartEndTime").Value Does that needs to converted